# Does bitnami wordpress stack allow multiple wordpress installs

Tags: wordpress, web, bitmap, bitnami, multiple-sites

I am currently using the bitnami wordpress stack, I have a website I'm working on but I also want to start another but I don't want to use multisite because I don't want them to share a database.

so is it possible to install another WordPress on bitnami? if yes how do i go about it?

Answer (score 2):

Bitnami Engineer here,

You can deploy another application on top of a running Bitnami instance by following these steps. They assume that your application will live in the /opt/bitnami/apps/myapp/ directory:

- Run the following commands to create the directories and assign the necessary permissions:

```
sudo mkdir /opt/bitnami/apps/myapp
sudo mkdir /opt/bitnami/apps/myapp/htdocs/
sudo mkdir /opt/bitnami/apps/myapp/conf            
sudo chown -R bitnami:daemon /opt/bitnami/apps/myapp/htdocs/
sudo chmod -R g+w /opt/bitnami/apps/myapp/htdocs/
```

- Create and edit the /opt/bitnami/apps/myapp/conf/httpd-prefix.conf file and add the line below to it:

```
Alias /myapp/ "/opt/bitnami/apps/myapp/htdocs/"
Alias /myapp "/opt/bitnami/apps/myapp/htdocs/"
Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/myapp/conf/httpd-app.conf"
```

- Create and edit the /opt/bitnami/apps/myapp/conf/httpd-app.conf file and add the content below to it. This is the main configuration file for your application, so modify it further depending on your application’s requirements.

```
<Directory /opt/bitnami/apps/myapp/htdocs/>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    <IfVersion < 2.3 >
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.3>
    Require all granted
    </IfVersion>
</Directory>
```

NOTE: If your application uses .htaccess files, you should change the AllowOverride None option to AllowOverride All. Find out how to move the .htaccess file content to the main server configuration file.

Once you have created the files and directories above, add the following line to the end of the main Apache configuration file at /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-prefix.conf, as shown below:

```
Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/myapp/conf/httpd-prefix.conf"
```

Restart the Apache server:

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache
```

You should now be able to access the application at http://SERVER-IP/myapp.

> Note: As WordPress requires a database, you will need to create a new database in the server

You can find more information about how to deploy a custom application in this guide of our documentation

https://docs.bitnami.com/general/apps/wordpress/administration/create-custom-application-php/

Thanks

Comment: this is all really confusing and overwhelming but i'll give it a try. thank you

Comment: and also what does a bitnami instance mean

Comment: I thought you had a machine in the cloud and that's why I was referring to it using "a bitnami instance". If you have a local installation, you need to change /opt/bitnami with your installation directory. You can find the info here: https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/apps/wordpress/administration/create-custom-application-php/