# Ubuntu Update PHP Version to 7.4 not recognized in php -v

Tags: php, ubuntu, bitnami

Base System: Ubuntu16.4; Bundled with a bitnami Wordpress installation

**Goal**:

Properly install PHP7.4

**Status**

Behaviour of the system after apt-get install php7.4:

- `find / -name php7*` => all Files I find are 7.4-related (their name includes php7.4)
- `sudo a2enmod php7*` => reports errors for any version except for php7.4
- `sudo /usr/bin/php7.4 -v` => PHP 7.0.30 (cli) (built: May 11 2018 16:56:24) ( ...

**BUT**

- `php -v` =>  **PHP 7.0.30** (cli) (built: May 11 2018 16:56:24)...
- Wordpress-Plugin to display version => Running PHP version: 7.0.30

How is this even possible? O_o

Comment: Can you share more details? How **exactly** did you install 7.4? Ubuntu 16.04 does not ship PHP 7.4, and to use the CLI you should also install the according CLI packages

Answer (score 1):

Bitnami Engineer here,

We do not provide WordPress deployments with PHP 7.4 but you can follow these steps to achieve it:

- Launch a new instance in LightSail with LAMP 7.3 (do not worry, we will remove its content and install LAMP 7.4). Please note that you will install a Bitnami stack so the 512MB or 1GB of RAM instance types will probably have problems during the installation.
- Install LAMP 7.4 in your instance (this will remove the LAMP 7.3 data as well)

```
cd /tmp
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh stop
sudo rm -rf /opt/bitnami
wget "https://downloads.bitnami.com/files/stacks/lampstack/7.4.7-0/bitnami-lampstack-7.4.7-0-linux-x64-installer.run
chmod +x ./bitnami-lampstack-7.4.7-0-linux-x64-installer.run
sudo ./bitnami-lampstack-7.4.7-0-linux-x64-installer.run --prefix /opt/bitnami
```

- Deploy WordPress following the steps explained in [this other Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62211406/does-bitnami-wordpress-stack-allow-multiple-wordpress-installs/62211962#62211962)
- and then migrate the data from one installation to the other one [using the All in One WordPress Migration plugin](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/how-to/migrate-wordpress/).

Once you confirm everything works as expected, you can stop your previous instance of WordPress.

Happy to help!

Comment: I tried to make all steps and got "Forbidden - You don't have permission to access this resource." when trying to access http://SERVER-IP/wordpress :(

Comment: Are you sure you configured the application using /wordpress and not /myapp? Please note that the information in the other Stack Overflow post uses /myapp when deploying the application. Could you access the application at some point during the installation?

Comment: First, I changed on all commands myapp to wordpress. Today, I ran all commands again with myapp, as you suggested, but it neither worked. I created on both cases a instance in Amazon Lightsail, but on both I got the same "Forbidden" error